# Stacking Z axis on multiple [1440x720] DataFrames (X, Y)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

Each datum represents a point in a 1440x720 image of the globe, The values are 0-9. Each new layer is of a higher elevation. I need to structure a `DataFrame` in a way that allows me to "connect the values" and create geometric shapes.

### main.py

```py
from typing import Iterable
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

INDEX = pd.Index(np.linspace(90, -90, 720), name="Latitudes")
COLUMNS = pd.Index(np.linspace(-180, 180, 1440), name="Longitudes")


def random_frame(n: int = 10) -> Iterable[pd.DataFrame]:
    for _ in range(n):
        data = np.random.randint(9, size=(720, 1440))
        yield pd.DataFrame(data, index=INDEX, columns=COLUMNS).stack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.concat(random_frame(), axis=1).T
    df.index = df.index.rename("Elevation") * 1000
    print(df)
```

### result

```
Latitudes         90.0                                                                                                              ...       -90.0                                                                                                            
Longitudes -180.000000 -179.749826 -179.499653 -179.249479 -178.999305 -178.749131 -178.498958 -178.248784 -177.998610 -177.748436  ...  177.748436  177.998610  178.248784  178.498958  178.749131  178.999305  179.249479  179.499653  179.749826  180.000000
Elevation                                                                                                                           ...                                                                                                                        
0                    2           2           3           8           4           2           0           0           7           0  ...           5           5           0           1           8           2           1           3           5           1
1000                 7           6           8           8           4           5           0           7           6           1  ...           7           2           8           3           2           0           0           2           4           6
2000                 0           3           0           5           3           2           0           2           6           1  ...           1           7           2           7           3           4           6           0           1           6
3000                 4           6           1           1           6           7           3           3           3           6  ...           5           4           5           3           4           2           2           5           7           3
4000                 8           8           1           8           0           3           6           4           8           3  ...           2           4           7           3           1           8           6           2           1           4
5000                 6           0           5           7           0           5           8           1           6           0  ...           8           8           8           0           4           4           8           6           2           3
6000                 2           1           5           2           1           6           6           6           8           5  ...           2           5           1           2           4           2           2           7           4           5
7000                 6           8           5           8           5           8           7           1           3           4  ...           8           2           0           5           1           7           6           3           7           0
8000                 0           2           0           7           7           4           5           4           2           5  ...           2           1           0           2           6           4           0           8           5           8
9000                 6           7           1           3           6           3           4           2           6           2  ...           8           8           1           4           7           7           2           6           7           8

[10 rows x 1036800 columns]
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me that the current code does what you want?

Comment: Also, it's likely that you'll want to merge this account into your [original one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/250991/jason-leaver). To do so, contact a CM via the contact link at the bottom of every page;
see this [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I submit to merge my accounts.  In terms of code, the random data is a bad example. Each datum represents an intensity of an aviation hazard (Icing & Turbulence).  End objective is to either produce a tile service heat map or `connect the dots` and create polygons for different intensities.

Comment: most of the live data I'm working with is all zeros.  With geospatial areas over the globe having  a polygon type structure to them typically with increasing intensities towards the center of the geometric shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latitude, longitude and elevation are all independent variables. So why doesn't the output have a three-level index? There's only one dependent variable, "Risk", which should be your only column.

`np.linspace(90, -90, 720)` is not good. Either include your endpoint and have 721 values, or exclude your endpoint and have 720 values. In either case the values should increment by exactly 0.25 (a quarter of one degree). Similar for `COLUMNS`. You've described these as "images of the globe". A (sane) image of the globe does not repeat pixels at the border of its longitudes, so I would expect that the longitudes use a half-open interval and the latitudes a closed interval.